# User management in Microsoft Access 2013 databases

Tags: mysql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am building a system using Microsoft Access 2013 that uses MySQL as a backend. I am trying to figure out a way to do some kind of basic user management, ideally in such a way that users would have to "log in" when they launch the database, and then their username would be easily accessible by the system while they are using it. I've tried searching for solutions, but most of them just tell me to use Office 365 or sharepoint, which are not options at the moment. Does anyone have an idea of how to accomplish this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend building your own user storage and login system. You'll basically need to create your own users table (in MySQL in your case), make forms to manage users, make a Login form, and write code to control the login process.

Logging in usually consists of checking some kind of credentials they type in against existing data in your users table. You can usually do this in Access with DLookup or DCount statements but I usually end up using a DAO or ADO recordset instead since I like to pull out more than one value from the User's table and I also like to write things back to it right away, like the LastLogin datetime, LastLogin computername, etc.

I actually wrote an example database which you can download [here](http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=203475). It needs a rewrite. I've changed quite a few of my practices since Jan, 2011. But give me another year and it would need another rewrite.

I usually program the login form so that the user enters their initials and then a password. If you go this route you need to have a unique index setup on the Initials field to prevent duplicates. If you're going to have a lot of users you need to use a Username instead, which could still theoretically be the users initials.

Here's what my code would look like to authenticate a user. Be aware that this is far from truly secure. This assumes that passwords are stored in plain text. Users could theoretically try to do SQL Inject from here because I'm not use a parametrized query or stripping out special characters from their input such as @ or ;.

```vb
Private Function AuthenticateUser() As Boolean

    Dim sInitials As String
    Dim sPassword As String
    sInitials = Trim(Nz(Me.txtInitials, ""))
    sPassword = Trim(Nz(Me.txtPassword, ""))

    If sInitials = "" Or sPassword = "" Then
        'Logging in with blank passwords is not allowed
        AuthenticateUser = False
        Exit Function
    End If

    If DCount("EmployeeID", "tblEmployees", "[Initials] = '" & Replace(sInitials, "'", "''") & "' AND Password = '" & Replace(sPassword, "'", "''") & "'", True) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Invalid Credentials."
        AuthenticateUser = False
        Exit Function
    Else
        Dim rs As New DAO.Recordset
        Dim sSQL As String
        sSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblEmployees WHERE initials = '" & Replace(sInitials, "'", "''") & "'"
        Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sSQL)
        If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then
            'Config is an instance of a User Defined Type. It could also be a class object.
            Config.UserInitials = rs("Initials")
            Config.UserFullName = rs("EmployeeName")
            Config.UserID = rs("EmployeeID")
            rs.Edit
            rs("LastLoginDateTime") = Now()
            rs("LastLoginComputer") = "Function Required to Get Computer Name"
            rs("ProgVersion") = "Your Program Version Number"
            rs("CurrentDbPath") = Left(CurrentProject.path & "\" & CurrentProject.Name, 254)
            rs.Update
        End If
        rs.Close
        Set rs = Nothing
        AuthenticateUser = True
    End If

End Function
```

In my applications I use a global object, in this case an instance of a User Defined Type, which I call Config. I store any kind of application runtime related settings in there for the duration of the runtime of the application. Of course this object gets destroyed when the user closes out of the application or when a code reset happens (which cannot happen in Access runtime, but does happen frequently during development). You could use a class object instead of a User Defined Type. Or you could use individual global variables for everything, which I don't recommend (that's what I used to do). A User Defined Type simply allows you to group global variables together and gives you an easy way to refer to them in your code during design time by typing in Config., which then brings up every option using Intellisense (assuming you have it enabled).

If you want your settings to survive a code reset, you need to use TempVars. TempVars became available with Access 2007. I do not use them now (contrary to my example database) because they are not strongly typed. There's no Intellisense to help you get the correct TempVar and you can technically refer to a TempVar that doesn't even exist and Access won't throw an error. I think TempVars is really just a Dictionary object with all of it's shortcomings, and the single benefit of surviving a code reset. I can imagine storing a Connection String in there, but I wonder if it's worth using TempVars for anything at all. If a code reset happens, my entire application needs to be reloaded anyway since I setup a lot of global objects and variables when the application first opens and the user first logs in.

FYI, in previous versions of Access there was user security built in. I think Microsoft discontinued that starting in 2007. I never really used it so I didn't miss it when it got discontinued.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I know this is generally what I need to do, but I'm struggling with some of the specifics. Can you go into some more detail about what the Login Form would look like, and the code that would control the login process? Once users are logged in, where is the username of the current user stored so that I can reference it? Is there then a way to control which parts of the Access system they can interact with based on their user type (as determined by some cell in the MySQL database)?