# How to CREATE GROUP and USER on VBA MS ACCESS

Tags: sql, vba, database, ms-access

I'm trying to create Groups and Users to include in the groups using VBA on MS Access 2016.
I found this explanation on docs.microfost.com:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/create-user-or-group-statement-microsoft-access-sql

When I try to execute the next code lines it retrieves me an error: 3290

```
Sub CriacaoUtilizador()
    Dim dbs As Database
    'Escolha do Ficheiro Microsoft DataBase:
    Set dbs = OpenDatabase("C:\Users\Utilizador\OneDrive\PartilhaOneDrive_Programacao\CodeRR\Teste00.mdb")
    'Criação de utilizador utz_utilizador00:
    dbs.Execute "CREATE USER utz_utilizador00 123 1;"
    dbs.Close
End Sub

Sub CriacaoGrupo()
    Dim dbs As Database
    'Escolha do Ficheiro Microsoft DataBase:
    Set dbs = OpenDatabase("C:\Users\Utilizador\OneDrive\PartilhaOneDrive_Programacao\CodeRR\Teste00.mdb")
    'Criação de grupo grp_grupo00:
    dbs.Execute "CREATE GROUP grp_grupo00 123 1;"
    dbs.Close
End Sub
```

Can you help me, please?
Thanks.

Comment: Edit question to provide the exact error message, not just the number. Which line triggers error?

Comment: AFAIK, Access does not have internal USER and GROUP management (not since Access 2003). The referenced documentation seems to be misleading. Perhaps it applies when Access is connecting to another db platform such as SQLServer, MySQL, Oracle. Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18615125/user-management-in-microsoft-access-2013-databases and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DxRpo496w_c.

Comment: And I just noticed your db is an mdb which you are running with Access 2016. Review https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-to-join-a-workgroup-in-access-2016/c76562ec-73ce-41f8-b28b-3f34bdb97e10

Comment: And before you ever try any code, have you setup the database with secuirty? Does the GUI settings for user group security work? You HAVE to do that first. I did not think 2016 supported user group security - 2013 does!. But if the database is secured correctly, then the UI settings should show this, and allow you to create + add and maintain users and their groups.  In other words, try creating a new user, and add them to security groups with the UI first - not by code.